# mapping the camera name to opencv camera index

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv, directshow

I used to use this function to map a camera name to camera index in v3.4.1 of opencv but I have this upgraded to v4.1.0. But this function doesn't work anymore. The camera index does not match up anymore. Any idea why this is the case and how to map it correctly?

I am actually using Emgu 4.1.0 and using c#. Below I am making use of DirectShowLib nuget to get a list of VideoInput devices. In v3, the order matched the opencv camera index perfectly. Not in v4, seems like the order is wrong.

```
using DirectShowLib;
private DsDevice[] directShowCameras = 
DsDevice.GetDevicesOfCat(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

    private int getCameraIndexForName(string name)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < directShowCameras.Count(); i++)
        {
            if(directShowCameras[i].Name.ToLower().Contains(name.ToLower()))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Seems like if I specify DShow when opening the camera index, it matches ok. But why is this? Has the default backend changed and if so what is it now and is it better?

Comment: Ok I have since figured out the default backend in 4.1.0 is MSMF (microsoft media foundation). Anyone know how I can get a list of video capture devices in c# using this framework? I suspect the indexes will match correctly then

Answer (score 2):

Turns out v4.1.0 priortizes MSMF instead of DirectShow. Also the enumeration of the cameras are different between these frameworks. So use this functions to convert a camera friendly name to camera index. This uses the SharpDx.MediaFoundation nuget library to call MSMF APIs in c#

```
    using SharpDX.MediaFoundation;
    public static int GetCameraIndexForPartName(string partName)
    {
        var cameras = ListOfAttachedCameras();
        for(var i=0; i< cameras.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (cameras[i].ToLower().Contains(partName.ToLower()))
            {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public static string[] ListOfAttachedCameras()
    {
        var cameras = new List<string>();
        var attributes = new MediaAttributes(1);
        attributes.Set(CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.SourceType.Guid, CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.SourceTypeVideoCapture.Guid);
        var devices = MediaFactory.EnumDeviceSources(attributes);
        for (var i = 0; i < devices.Count(); i++)
        {
            var friendlyName = devices[i].Get(CaptureDeviceAttributeKeys.FriendlyName);
            cameras.Add(friendlyName);
        }
        return cameras.ToArray();
    }
```

Just to be 100% that the newer MSMF is used I would also specify this backend when creating the camera object.

```
capture = new VideoCapture(index, VideoCapture.API.Msmf);
```

This backend seems to work a lot better for cameras including the macbook air's inbuilt camera.